# execution of a local shell script on remote server (without copying it on remote server) using expect scripting

Tags: shell, expect

I am new to world of scripting. I am getting problem while executing local shell script on remote server using expect script.
my script is following

```
VAR=$(/home/local/RD/expect5.45/expect -c "
spawn -noecho ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST $CMD
match_max 100000
expect \"*?assword:*\"
send -- \"$PASS\r\"
send -- \"\r\"
send  \"exit\n\r\"
expect eof
")
```

It is working fine if CMD is basic commands like `df -kh;top`.
But I need to collect several stats on remote server for which i have created a shell script.
I have tried following with no luck

```
spawn -noecho ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST 'bash -s' < localscript.sh
```

its not able to pick and execute localscript on remote server. 
Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I tried something like this, I quickly grew weary of using `expect(1)` to try to respond to the password prompts correctly. When I finally spent the ten minutes to learn how to [create an `ssh` key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen), [copy the key to the remote system](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id), and [set up the `ssh-agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) to make key-based logins easier to automate, I never had trouble running scripts remotely:

```
ssh remotehost "commands ; go ; here"
```

First, check if you need to create the key or if you already have one:

```
ls -l ~/.ssh/id_*
```

If there are no files listed, then run:

```
ssh-keygen
```

and answer the prompts.

Once your key is generated, copy it to the remote system:

```
ssh-copy-id remote
```

Most modern systems run `ssh-agent(1)` as part of the desktop start up; to determine if you've got the agent started already, run:

```
ssh-add -l
```

If you see "The agent has no identities.", then you're good to go. If you see "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." then you'll have to do some research about the best place to insert the `ssh-agent(1)` into your environment. Or, forgo the agent completely, it is just a nice convenience.

Add your key, perhaps with a timeout so it is only valid for a short while:

```
ssh-add -t 3600
```

Now test it:

```
ssh remote "df -hk ; ps auxw ; ip route show ; free -m"
```

`expect(1)` is definitely a neat tool, but authentication on remote systems is easier (and more safely) accomplished with SSH keys.

Comment: Tnx for quick reply. Its not related to ssh-key. As "ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST 'bash -s' < localscript.sh" working perfectly on the system. I need to automate execution of local script on remote server. Thats the reason I am using expect. But with expect script, ssh is not able to read localscript.sh. Hence spawn -noecho ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST 'bash -s' < localscript.sh is not able to read localscript.sh. I think its a problem of arguments(localscript.sh) to ssh in spawn.

Comment: Hrm. If you're sending the command to execute as a parameter to the `ssh` command, then you shouldn't need to send `exit` in your `expect(1)` script...

Comment: its not working after removing send. I m trying something like this spawn ssh user@remoteserver "local script to execute on remote server" . is thr any other way out to do the same thing.

Comment: it's possible to 'export' a complete local script 'over the wire' to a remote machine using ssh, i.e. ssh user@host "$( cat localScript)". but can be problematic if localscript contains flow control and wildcards. Good luck.

Comment: Will this work with expect i.e. spawn ssh user@host "$( cat localScript)"? I am away from the system. i'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: its not working. spawn ssh user@host "$( cat localScript)" reads first line of the script and for rest lines showing error.

Comment: Can't speak for `spawn ssh...` Expect will probly add another layer of complexity to this. I meant ssh with password files setup on remote machines. Then you can execute scripts remotely or 'over-the-wire'. You need to learn how to read debug output of the shell (maybe you know already). `set -vx`. -v=verbose, shows each block of code to be executed (or simple pipelines or single commands) while -x (?) shows the values of the variables as they're expanded. Experiment with super-simple scripts for `$( cat localScript)` to see it work, then add in more code to see what causes errors. Good luck.

Comment: Also, I notice you're using `...'bash -s' < localscript.sh`. That is very similar to my technique with `$(cat script)`. By messing around with your quoting you should be able to get a localscript.sh to be 'passed-over-the-wire' to the remote ssh target, without any need for expect. Where is the password prompt coming from? from ssh or some remote application you're trying to startup, (like a database?). Again, start expermenting with simple commands in your localscript.sh to get it to work basically, then add in features to see what makes it break. Also for tsting, take out the top line #!/...